# Bind domain name with an IP address with port

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, tomcat

I have a web application which runs locally in out network (hosted in `Windows Server 2019` and deployed in `Tomcat` server ) and it is accessible from `http://192.168.19.29:8080/myapp/`.

I configured our router and set a port forward, in order to access the web application outside the network from `http://static_externa_ip:3000`. What I want is to bind this ip with a subdomain.

In DNS settings of my domain name I added a A Record

- Type: A
- Name: myapp
- data: static_externa_ip

And now I can access my web application from `myapp.mydomain.com:3000/myapp/`
Is it possible to add another type of record in order to simplify my url to `myapp.mydomain.com` ?

I tried to add in the data field the `static_externa_ip:8080/myapp` but it wasn't a valid input.

Then is it possible to purchase a SSL certificate and add it the Tomcat Server, so I would access my web application securely outside?

Comment: if yozr application supports srv it can be used for this

Comment: Check out letsencrypt for the SSL certificate. Also, if you have configured the sub domain correctly in the DNS and someone requests subdomain.example.com:3000 the your port forward should forward to your app.

Comment: Is `myapp` only application that is served at the port 80? If so you can: put content of `myapp` into the `webapps/ROOT` (or deploy it as ROOT.war); now if you port forward `80` to `http://192.168.19.29:8080` you application should be accesible from outside at address myapp.mydomain.com. But as @davidgo wrote, best solution for this situation would be introducing reverse proxy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ye canna change the laws of DNS.

Comment: The fact that what I asked cant be implemented, doesn't mean that the question if off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no usable record type you can use. The http and https protocols do not support SRV records which would be required.

This kind of problem can be solved with a reverse proxy if your hardware supports it.